# Slick carousel slider-nav items get hidden off screen If I resize the window

Tags: javascript, jquery, slick.js

Right now `slick` `slider-nav` items get hidden off screen If I `resize` the `window`.

Here is what happening to the `slick`, first `onload/refresh` the page of course its working fine but when I `click` any number `item` like number `5` and `resize` the `window` all slides before the `active slide` get `hidden` off `screen`.

It would be great if it can be fixed using `js`.

To better understand check the images and code below. Also here is the pen code [https://codepen.io/](https://codepen.io/graydirt/pen/LYXrjKL).
**Images:**
[image]
[image]

**Updates:**.
Code have been updated and its working fine here [https://codepen.io/](https://codepen.io/graydirt/pen/LYXrjKL). However other JS solutions/alternatives are welcome without using CSS of `.slick-track: left: 0 !important;`

**Code snippet:**

```js
function slickBarWithCounter() {
    $('.slider-for').slick({
        slidesToShow: 1,
        slidesToScroll: 1,
        arrows: false,
        infinite: false,
        draggable: false,
        swipe: false,
        fade: false,
        swipeToSlide: false,
        touchMove: false,
        asNavFor: '.slider-nav'
    });
    $('.slider-nav').slick({
        slidesToShow: 5,
        slidesToScroll: 1,
        asNavFor: '.slider-for',
        dots: false,
        arrows: false,
        infinite: false,
        focusOnSelect: true,
        variableWidth: true
    });

    function barAndCounter(index = 0) {
        //bar
        var progressBar = $('.progress-bar__inner');
        var itemWidth = 100 / $('.slider-nav .icons').length;
        var progress = (index + 1) * itemWidth;
        progressBar.css('width', progress + '%');
        //counter
        var sliderNav = $('.slider-nav');
        var totalSlides = sliderNav.slick('getSlick').slideCount;
        $(".left__count").text('0' + ++index);
        $(".right__count").text('0' + totalSlides);
    }
    // Will be triggered on page load
    barAndCounter();
    // Will be triggered on slider click
    $('.slider-nav .icons').on('click', function() {
        var index = $(this).index();
        barAndCounter(index);
    });
}

slickBarWithCounter();
```

```css
body{
  background:#ccc;
}
.container {
  font-family:Arial;
  max-width:800px;
  display:block;
  margin:0 auto;
  position: relative;
}
.slider-content {
  background: #fff;
  padding: 3rem;
  font-size: 3rem;
  text-align: center;
  height: 200px !important;
}
.slider-nav .slick-list .slick-current {
  background: green;
  color: white;
}
.slider-nav-wrapper {
  position: absolute;
  left:3rem;
  right: 3rem;
  bottom: 3rem;
}
.slider-nav-wrapper .icons {
  background: black;
  color: #3498db;
  font-size: 1rem;
  margin: 0 .5rem;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
}
.progress-bar {
  width: 100%;
  height: 2px;
  background: gray;
  position: relative;
}
.progress-bar__inner {
  background: green;
  position: absolute;
  height: 6px;
  top: -2px;
  left: 0;
  width: 0;
  transition: width 0.3s ease;
}
.left__count {
  padding-right: 1rem;
}
.right__count {
  padding-left: 1rem;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/slick-carousel@1.8.1/slick/slick.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/slick-carousel@1.8.1/slick/slick.css"/>
<div class="container">
  <div class="slider slider-for">
    <div class="slider-content">1</div>
    <div class="slider-content">2</div>
    <div class="slider-content">3</div>
    <div class="slider-content">4</div>
    <div class="slider-content">5</div>
  </div>
  <div class="slider-nav-wrapper">
   <div class="slider slider-nav">
      <div class="icons">1</div>
      <div class="icons">2</div>
      <div class="icons">3</div>
      <div class="icons">4</div>
      <div class="icons">5</div>
    </div>
    <div style="display: flex; align-items: center; margin-top: 1rem;">
      <div class="left__count">01</div>
      <div class="progress-bar">
        <div class="progress-bar__inner"></div>
      </div> 
      <div class="right__count">05</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Updates:**.
Code have been updated and its working fine below and also here [https://codepen.io/](https://codepen.io/graydirt/pen/LYXrjKL). However other JS solutions/alternatives are welcome without using CSS of .slick-track: left: 0 !important;

```js
function slickBarWithCounter() {
    $('.slider-for').slick({
        slidesToShow: 1,
        slidesToScroll: 1,
        arrows: false,
        infinite: false,
        draggable: false,
        swipe: false,
        fade: false,
        swipeToSlide: false,
        touchMove: false,
        asNavFor: '.slider-nav'
    });
    $('.slider-nav').slick({
        slidesToShow: 5,
        slidesToScroll: 1,
        asNavFor: '.slider-for',
        useTransform: false,
        dots: false,
        arrows: false,
        infinite: false,
        focusOnSelect: true,
        variableWidth: true
    });

    function barAndCounter(index = 0) {
        //bar
        var progressBar = $('.progress-bar__inner');
        var itemWidth = 100 / $('.slider-nav .icons').length;
        var progress = (index + 1) * itemWidth;
        progressBar.css('width', progress + '%');
        //counter
        var sliderNav = $('.slider-nav');
        var totalSlides = sliderNav.slick('getSlick').slideCount;
        $(".left__count").text('0' + ++index);
        $(".right__count").text('0' + totalSlides);
    }
    // Will be triggered on page load
    barAndCounter();
    // Will be triggered on slider click
    $('.slider-nav .icons').on('click', function() {
        var index = $(this).index();
        barAndCounter(index);
    });
}

slickBarWithCounter();
```

```css
body{
  background:#ccc;
  font-family: Arial;
}
.container {
  max-width:800px;
  display:block;
  margin:0 auto;
  position: relative;
}
.slider-content {
  background: #fff;
  padding: 1rem;
  font-size: 3rem;
  text-align: center;
  height: 200px !important;
}

.slider-nav .slick-track{
  left: 0 !important;
}
.slider-nav .slick-list .slick-current {
  background: green;
  color: white;
}
.slider-nav-wrapper {
  position: absolute;
  left:1rem;
  right: 1rem;
  bottom: 3rem;
}
.slider-nav-wrapper .icons {
  background: black;
  color: #3498db;
  font-size: 1rem;
  margin: 0 .5rem;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
}
.progress-bar {
  width: 100%;
  height: 2px;
  background: gray;
  position: relative;
}
.progress-bar__inner {
  background: green;
  position: absolute;
  height: 6px;
  top: -2px;
  left: 0;
  width: 0;
  transition: width 0.3s ease;
}
.left__count {
  padding-right: 1rem;
}
.right__count {
  padding-left: 1rem;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/slick-carousel@1.8.1/slick/slick.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/slick-carousel@1.8.1/slick/slick.css"/>
<h2 style="text-align: center; color: black; font-weight:bold; padding: 1rem;">Slick Carousel</h2>
<div class="container">
  <div class="slider slider-for">
    <div class="slider-content">1</div>
    <div class="slider-content">2</div>
    <div class="slider-content">3</div>
    <div class="slider-content">4</div>
    <div class="slider-content">5</div>
  </div>
  <div class="slider-nav-wrapper">
   <div class="slider slider-nav">
      <div class="icons">1</div>
      <div class="icons">2</div>
      <div class="icons">3</div>
      <div class="icons">4</div>
      <div class="icons">5</div>
    </div>
    <div style="display: flex; align-items: center; margin-top: 1rem;">
      <div class="left__count">01</div>
      <div class="progress-bar">
        <div class="progress-bar__inner"></div>
      </div> 
      <div class="right__count">05</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```